# Can I do multiple fetch in a single component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am using react as my frontend and express.js as my backend. I new to both framework. I have a component called Papers and I am trying to first upload some documents to the backend server through fetch post then perform some operation on the server side and then I am trying to get back the result from server in the same handler. My code for the handler looks like this:

```
        handleDrop(files) {
          var data = new FormData();

          alert((files[0]) instanceof File);
          files.forEach((file, index) => {
            data.append('file' + index, file);
          });

          fetch('/file_upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
          });

          // the second fetch would crash the app.
          /*fetch('/file_upload').then(function(data){
              return data.json();
          }).then( json => {
              this.setState({
                  papers: json
              });
              console.log(json);
          });*/
        }
```

My express backend code for the get method is :

```
app.get('/file_upload', function(req, res){
    // testing
    res.send({name:"lol"});
});
```

The problem right now is the second fetch would crash the express app. Since I am new to react and express, can someone please give me some hints if I am doing this in the right way? Thanks!

link to server code: https://github.com/kaiwenshi/learn-webpack/blob/master/src/server/index.js

Comment: First of all, you're sending **POST** request and on showing server side part for  **GET**. 
Second, you can use response body to get an answer in same fetch request

Comment: @GeorgiyDubrov Sorry about the confusion, the post method is kind of long so I did not post it. It's on the github link now.

Answer (score 0):

Express code should look like this if you want to do a POST:

```
app.post('/file_upload', function(req, res){
    // testing
    res.send({name:"lol"});
});
```

And you only need to do one call of fetch. The response (`{name: 'lol'}`) will be in the promise:

```
    handleDrop(files) {
      var data = new FormData();

      alert((files[0]) instanceof File);
      files.forEach((file, index) => {
        data.append('file' + index, file);
      });

      fetch('/file_upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      }).then(function(data){
          return data.json();
      }).then( json => {
          this.setState({
              papers: json
          });
          console.log(json); // logs {name: 'lol'}
      });
    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! So I tried to add the res.send in my post method and modified my react fetch code based on your suggestion. This time there is no error but I get nothing back? Do you have any idea why this happens? Thanks!

Comment: @Rockingchief Can you confirm that you get nothing back even when using a simple `app.post` method, like the one I mentioned, that does nothing other than send a simple reply 'lol'? Your `app.post` in the Github link you sent is pretty complicated, and I'd rather rule that complication out.

Comment: So I comment that part out and still get nothing back.

Comment: @Rockingchief Can you try making your fetch line look like this? I spun up a server that should send back data in exactly the same way `fetch('https://IncomparableGleefulSpecialist--MitchLillie.repl.co/testing', {`

Comment: So I just modified my fetch code but there's still nothing showing up. I am not sure if you can return data in a post request? Cause I feel like it should be the job of a get request? Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at the console, I get a Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0. Any suggestions? Thanks!